# MVC foreach set item.ID to model.ID

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a form that shows all the available hotel rooms, each room has a button that does a HttpPost if clicked, I have made a property in the BookingViewModel called 'RoomID'. I would like to assign the item.RoomID to Model.RoomID so I can use it in my controller to get the id from the selected room but i'm not sure how to achieve this.

### ChooseRoom View

```
@foreach (var item in Model.AvailableRooms)
{
    <li class="room-item clearfix">
        <h5>@item.Name</h5>
        <div class="room-list-left">
            <img src="@item.Image" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="room-list-right">
            <div class="room-meta">
                <ul>
                    <li><span>Occupancy:</span> @item.Adults Adults @item.Childs Children</li>
                    @if (item.SmokingRoom)
                    {
                        <li><span>Smoking Allowed:</span> Yes</li>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <li><span>Smoking Allowed:</span> No</li>
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="room-price">
                <p class="price">From: <span>$@item.Price</span> / Night</p>
            </div>
            <div class="clearboth"></div>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("chooseroom", "booking", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <input class="button2" type="submit" value="Select Room" />
            }
```

### BookingController

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ChooseRoom(BookingViewModel vm)
{
    BookingViewModel bookingObj = GetBooking();
    bookingObj.SelectedRoom = Repository.GetRoomByID(vm.RoomID);      
    return View("reservation", bookingObj);
}
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update your begin form as below

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("chooseroom", "booking", FormMethod.Post))
{
   <input type="hidden" name="RoomId" value="@item.RoomID" />
   <input class="button2" type="submit" value="Select Room" />
}
```

Just need to provide input tags having the same name as your ViewModel property.

Answer (score 1):

You could add inputs in foreach loop , it should be inside form. Something like this `<input name="Model.AvailableRooms[index].RoomID" value="Id Here"/>`

Or if you want to select one Room you should use ajax and post id.

If I'm not wrong you form is in loop,so you could add hidden input with id

```
@Html.HiddenFor(c => c.AvailableRooms[index].RoomID)
```